# How to convert non-standard sample range to standard

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, matlab

I'm working on a project to record sound from a Raspberry Pi. I have ADC values raning from 0 to 4095. I can convert it to an audio file and hear my voice. This is my algorithm for getting sample ranges in MATLAB:  (ADC Value / 2047.5) - 1

It works great but the problem is that is not standard

[image]

I need a standard sample range like a Windows audio recorder 32768 and -32768.

Comment: Don't overthink it. The exact same thing you do with any graph. If I gave you y=sin(x) and told you I wanted it centered around +11 instead of zero with an amplitude of 13, what would you do to it?

Comment: If your ADC input DC offset is not biased to center of the ADC midpoint value then it is a bit late to try centering the clipped waveform back to center after the ADC conversion. How do you feed audio in to ADC? Show the schematics, edit them in the question. Are you sure the range is to 4095 or is it only to 2047? Or some other value? Which ADC is used?

Comment: Hi  @Justme
My analog converter is 12 bit and I use op-amp max4466 preamplifier for adc input

Comment: You can remove an offset value of -0.5 by adding 0.5 to each sample.

Comment: user1850479 in matlab ?

Comment: In a spreadsheet if you like! In whatever tool works for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be conflating some terminology. Sample rate is based on how often you sample and is measured in Hz (1/s). Bit-depth is how many bits of resolution each sample contains (e.g. 8 bits, 16 bits, or 24 bits per sample).

In audio recording, these two concepts are sometimes combined by multiplying the two values together to get a value in, for example, kilobits per second (kbps), and it tells you sort of the "information rate" of your signal. A (there's not just one) standard sample rate in audio recording 48kHz at 24-bit resolution.

If you sample at a resolution that is lower, like you are using 12-bit by the sounds of it based on 0-4096 ADC values, you can "fake" the resolution by applying a linear transformation to you readings to change the range and baseline value of your readings to suit a file format without introducing a distortion.

It's not going to create new information, so I wouldn't expect your recording to sound better by doing this, but it might make your playback software happier.

So if you want to map values from 0 - 4096 to the range -32768 - 32768... you would do something like this:

```
OUTPUT = (INPUT - 2048) * (32768 / 2048)
```

Comment: Hi @vicatcu
You are right, my ADC converter is 12-bit and my sampling rate is 48khz

Comment: What formula should I use?

Comment: updated with a formula... it's just what comes out of a point-slope formulation of a line that maps your input range to your output range.

Comment: thank you so much for your help but I need a negative and a positive peak

Comment: @Jason Please think about what I said in my comment. It is fairly obvious you are just looking at the equation given to you and without trying to understand it to do which will not get you far in the future. This is direct application of basic high school math about graphs (scaling and translation) with no twists or turns.

Comment: Hi @DKNguyen
You mean I have to enter the analog value into the sine function

Comment: @jason No. Did you not learn how to translate and scale graphs? For example, how y=cos(x) changes if you go y=Acos(x) or y = cos(Bx) or y = cos(x)+C or y=cos(x+D) and how to combine them? Not just sines and cosines, any function.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about

Comment: @Jason Then no answer anyone gives you here is going to make sense. Learn this: https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-transformations.html. Then enter a sample functions such as \$x, x^2, x^3\$ and \$sin(x)\$ into this https://www.desmos.com/ and experiment.

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do two things to your data:

- convert from unsigned-binary to 2's complement
- left-justify in a 16-bit sample

For the first step to make 2's complement, *add* 2048 to the input, then truncate to 12 bits:

```
  * 0xFFF + 0x800 = 0x17FF, truncate to 0x7FF (+2047)
  * 0x800 + 0x800 = 0x1000, truncate to 0x000 (0)
  * 0x7FF + 0x800 = 0x0FFF, truncate to 0xfff (-1)
  * 0x000 + 0x800 = 0x0800, truncate to 0x800 (-2048)
```

We now have 12-bit 2's complement. Next step, shift up by 4 bits to left-align in a 16-bit word:

```
  * 0x7FF << 4 = 0x7FF0
  * 0x000 << 4 = 0x0000
  * 0xFFF << 4 = 0xFFF0
  * 0x800 << 4 = 0x8000
```

This will yield normalized 16-bit sample data.

In pseudo-C code this would be:

```
sample_16bit = ((ADC_sample_12bit + 2048) | 0xfff) << 4;
```

Why do it this way? It avoids needing more than 16 bits and only uses shifts and adds.

Comment: Hi @hacktastical
can you more explain code please ?

Comment: There's a number of ways to convert the value that will yield a numerically correct result. However, since you're tying to make samples of a specific word length (16 bits), you have to make sure that whatever math you use results in 16-bit values. The sequence I show is guaranteed to do that.

Comment: There are codecs for it ?

Comment: Excuse me, I'll take your time

Comment: What? No. This is just preprocessing the PCM audio data to fit in a 2's complement 16-bit container, the standard for raw audio PCM data.

Comment: @ hacktastical 
I have raw adc value, there is software or code to convert it to normal sound ?